# What fonts are used in Kinfolk Magazine

Tags: font-identification

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what fonts are used on Kinfolk magazine, more specifically:

1. Cover Title Font & Secondary Title
2. The font that is used in the articles within the magazine

I would appreciate if you can saw the sizes of these fonts respectively as well. Thank You.

Note: I have also attached two images, the first one showing the front cover titles, and the second showing the fonts used in the magazine interior.

[image: Front Cover]
[image: Magazine Interior]

Comment: You can always use this "What The Font" tool to assist you in IDing fonts: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ Just crop those images and upload there; it should help.

Comment: Note, no one here can determine the actual font sizes from scanned or photographed copies. The scan/photo will alter the size of type in *mist* instances. Most of the time, a hard copy of a magazine would need to be examined to determine font sizes.

Comment: The main title is Trajan with what appears to be one of the Franklin Gothic family as the subtitle font. Inside, it's Franklin Gothic (probably; the images are small and indistinct) and American Garamond.

Answer (score 2):

Subject font size:

Note: I am a little bit afraid answering this, but I think a *Type Gauge* (or *Type Ruler*, *Typometer*) would help you identify the font sizes of your example. There you can read the font size, line spacing and line width. I am working with a Typometer for a couple of years.

You can get one [here](http://www.leesartshop.com/opaque-type-gauge-ruler.html) or [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001E1THWG).

[image: Type gauge]